# Porting ESP8266 SDK to ESP32

Tags: c, embedded, kaa, esp32

Does anyone have experience with porting the kaa-client SDK, which supports only ESP8266, to the newer ESP32?

I have started with adapting the TCP APIs.

Comment: _has somebody experience?_ is this your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look here in order to see how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Moreover, porting an SDK is quite strange....

Comment: Please, add "kaa" tag to such a questions.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no full description how to port the Kaa C SDK on a specific platform, but we are working on this item. Thus I am going to describe general steps here.

Kaa C SDK doesn't need any OS. 
To use the Kaa C SDK on a specific platform, you must implement the following routines:

Mandatory:
Dynamic allocation.
Network [communication](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_tcp_utils.h).
Time routine.
Public key [generation](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_key_utils.h) (it may be some hard-coded key, see the ESP8266 [demo](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/listfiles/platform/esp8266/CMakeLists.txt#L49)).
SHA-1 [calculation](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_sha.h) (you may use a [default](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl/common/sha.c) implementation).

Optional (it means you can provide empty implementation):
File system interaction ([one](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_configuration_persistence.h), [two](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_status.h)).
Debug [logging](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform/ext_system_logger.h).

This [page](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Linux#Linux-CendpointSDK) describes configuration parameters for building the Kaa C SDK on various platforms.
Here are instructions how to develop applications based on the Kaa C SDK on TI [СС32XX](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Texas+Instruments+CC3200) and [ESP8266](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/ESP8266) platforms.
Also, you can find [here](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/) the source code of demo applications for these platforms.

Second - if you are using a protocol which is not yet officially supported, you can implement a [custom transport](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Creating+custom+transport).

The alternative option is when you integrate the Kaa SDK into a gateway (we call it "actor gateway"). The actor gateway instantiates an endpoint actor per each physical device. The actor handles communication with the actual device and presents itself to the cloud as a virtual representation of the sensor, etc.

The actor gateway can be effectively used when you can’t install the Kaa SDK on your device or you need to use some sophisticated protocol for device-server connectivity.